# slide animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Does anyone have an opinion about handling this animation in flutter?

when u swipe left the front card goes left and left bottom then the behind card size becomes bigger and replace the first card.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar once. What you want to do is use a GestureDetector and listen to onPanUpdate, add a child with a AnimatedPositioned and if needed a Rotated widget.

You can take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ikbendewilliam/97ffce54f4bc5853b2f3a905d5b98fd9) which is a class from a hackathon we did.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: _onPanStart,
        onPanEnd: _onPanEnd,
        onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            AnimatedPositioned(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: _duration),
                top: _positionY,
                left: _positionX,
                child: Container(constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight, maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth), child: widget.child))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks but there is no project in github. it shows 404

Comment: Turns out, I can't share the repo and it's private, my bad

Comment: No problem can u please post the code of that class I mean whole class please

Comment: I added a gist to my post

Answer (score 0):

I would combine those two:

1 - [AnimatedPositioned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC3s2YdtWt8) - to move the widget by some offset

2 - [AnimatedRotation](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_rotation) - so that you can turn the rotation while it is moving

Comment: thanks I will check it out